# change css position to fixed on a created canvas with js

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So the idea is - I want to get the canvas position style to be fixed through js, so I don't get the scroll bars.
The thing is - I can change the style easily with chrome inspector and all works fine, but js refuses to corporate...

```
function setup() {
      //full screen setup
      canvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth*2,window.innerHeight*2);
      canStyle = canvas.style;
      canvas.style.position = "fixed";
      mainWrap = document.getElementById('mainWrap');
      canvas.parent(mainWrap);
```

This is what I get instead :
[image: canvas is really not fixed]
The html, body and main wrap are 100% , just the way I want it, but the canvas itself is stretched, but not fixed...
I really don't know what I'm doing wrong... Ideas?

[image]

The manual chrome inspector edit does the job...
Whole Code

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sky</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libs/p5.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="libs/p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="star.js"></script>
  <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainWrap">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**css:**

```
html, body, #mainWrap {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:0px;
}
body{
  background-color: #222222;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var mainWrap;
var sky = [];
var x;
var y;
var trans = false;
function setup() {
  //full screen setup
  canvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth*2,window.innerHeight*2);
  canStyle = canvas.style;
  canvas.style.position = "fixed";
  mainWrap = document.getElementById('mainWrap');
  canvas.parent(mainWrap);

  for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        var star = new Star(i, random(width),random(height), Math.floor(random(1,4)));
        sky[i] = star;
        console.log(sky[i]);
  }
}
function draw() {
  background(34,34,34);
  x = mouseX;
  y = mouseY;
  if(trans === false){
    translate(x-(width/2),y-(height/2));
  }
  for (var i=0; i < sky.length; i++){
      sky[i].show();
      sky[0].fall(0.4,0.3);
  }
}
```

**Star obj:**

```
function Star(id,xCord, yCord, parallax) {
  this.parrlax = parallax;
  this.id = id;
  this.x = xCord;
  this.y = yCord;
  this.r = parallax;
  noStroke();

  this.show = function(){
    fill(255,255,255, random(30*this.parrlax,this.parrlax*40));
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
  }
this.fall = function(xMove, yMove) {
  this.x += xMove;
  this.y += yMove;
  fill(100,100,100);
  ellipse(this.x,this.y,3,3);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Comment: why do you need it fixed instead of just 100% width and height?

Comment: Because i need the canvas larger than the body (i am doing a mouse parallax effect)

Comment: Your canvas is twice the width and height of the screen, so it's going to create scrollbars. You could try rewriting `createCanvas(window.innerWidth*2,window.innerHeight*2);` as `createCanvas(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);` and see if that helps, but if not I'd recommend just adding `overflow:hidden;` to the body and html

Comment: @lonut sure, just a sec

Comment: You don't need the canvas that big for a parallax effect. You can make the canvas to take the window width and height and handle the parallax effect inside canvas.

Comment: @lonut, sure i could try that, but i am so close to finish this way...

Comment: @Djave I don't think you caught my thought, check the picture i added.

Comment: @lonut added all code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `createCanvas` is a [method form P5.js](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCanvas), you need to access the [underlying DOM element](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/elt) of the created canvas:

```
canvas = createCanvas(window.innerWidth*2,window.innerHeight*2);
// canvas here refers to an instance of P5 canvas, not a HTML5 canvas element, 
// but the real DOM canvas is available as either .canvas or .elt
canvas.elt.style.position = "fixed";
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, genius!